# criando atalho html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia, 
Eu coloco `accesskey="i"` para criar um atalho no html, porém preciso adicionar duas letras, como faço?

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btnEntidades" ng-click="salvarEntidades()" data-dismiss="modal" accesskey="s">Salvar</button>`

Mas como colocar `e+p` exemplo?

Comment: Não é possível atribuir mais de que uma tecla ao atributo `accesskeys` [Veja este artigo](http://jkorpela.fi/forms/accesskey.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não encontrei um método saudável de fazer isso apenas com o atributo **accesskey**, mas com javascript/jQuery além de ser relativamente simples, você pode prevenir ações padrões do navegador, como no exemplo explicado a baixo:

```js
//Crie um map para as keys que você vai querer utilizar
var map = {65: false, 81: false,17:false};
//Usando o evento keydown partindo do documento
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  //Prevenindo o default
  e.preventDefault();
  //Caso a tecla pressionada tenha sido definida no mapa acima entra  no contexto
  if (e.keyCode in map) {
      //Muda o key pressionado para true no mapa
      map[e.keyCode] = true;
      //Verificando os keys
      if (map[65] && map[81]) {
          //Faça algo ao pressionar Q + A
          console.log('Pressionado Q + A');
      }
      if (map[17] && map[65]) {
          //Faça algo ao pressionar CTRL + A
          console.log('Pressionado CTRL + A');
      }
  }
}).keyup(function (e) {
  //Aqui limpando e devolvendo o valor false para o mapa pra saber que foi solto o botão
  if (e.keyCode in map) {
      map[e.keyCode] = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```